# html table side by side issue on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Hello I have to html table, the css applyed to them is as following :

```
<table style="float:left;width:30%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Row1Cell1</td>
        <td>Row1Cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:70%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Row2Cell1</td>
        <td>Row2Cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In firefox when I reduce the page a the maximum size the tables stay always side by side but in Chrome and IE9 they are aligned one below the other when the size is reduced to the maximum. So please how can I fix that ?

Comment: @rid The question states that this is an issue in Chrome, and the contents states that in Chrome, they are aligned below each other. From that I conclude that they should be side-by-side.

Comment: yes side by side always even if I reduce the size, sorry if I did not say that clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the first table can't resize further than the minimum width each cell takes up, since the contents of the cells won't wrap unless there is whitespace where it can wrap.

I've tried all of the 'solutions' posted here, and it seems like the general idea of what Anthed is suggesting is the only way this can actually work perfectly.

Here is my code, based on what Anthed posted, but with a few very important edits:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%">

      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>Row1Cell1</td>
          <td>Row1Cell2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
    <td style="width:70%">

      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>Row2Cell1</td>
          <td>Row2Cell2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**See live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9vSFf/1/).

The main differences:

1. I've changed the use of the **very** old, deprecated ([see bottom of this section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes)) `width` attribute, and changed it to use the `style` attribute instead.
2. I've added a width style to the nested tables too, otherwise they'd not take up the full width anyway

The reason other answers didn't work is because the tables will always try to take up more space than they can when they're reduced to a smaller width than what their content would allow, based on their content's text content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<table style="float:left;width:30%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Row1Cell1</td>
        <td>Row1Cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="float:left;width:70%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Row2Cell1</td>
        <td>Row2Cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Put both this tables in the `div` with `100%` and you need to `float` both the tables.

**UPDATE**

It depends on the browser where to lock screen but you can lock window screen with `min-width` property with `overflow:auto` **css** during resizing browser window. Just replace above `div` with belowed one. Other code remains same.

```
<div style="width:100%;min-width:700px;overflow:auto;">
```

It should work!

Comment: @OussamaLord: It depends on browser `view port`. Best way to lock screen is to set `min-width` to its `div` container with `overflow:auto`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful but should work:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">
      <table><tr><td>Row1Cell1</td><td>Row1Cell2</td></tr></table>
    </td>
    <td width="70%">
      <table><tr><td>Row2Cell1</td><td>Row2Cell2</td></tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'd need style="width:100%" on the table, and you [really shouldn't use the deprecated `width` attribute anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes).

Comment: No this won't work. The **deprecated** (!) `width` attribute only takes absolute pixel values. Units are not allowed. Once again, you should *change to the `style` attribute*.

Comment: I confirm, and the ideal solution would be to replace both main cells by div and associated styles (float, display, ...)

Comment: Please have a look on my other answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use css to force them side-by-side.

```
table{
    float: left;
}
```

or

```
table{
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that the second table comes over the first one when the width of the window becomes short, try this :

```
<style type="text/css">
  #div1 {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
  }

  #div2 {
    width: 70%;
  }
</style>

<div id="div1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1Cell1</td>
      <td>Row1Cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2Cell1</td>
      <td>Row2Cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").css("min-width", $("#div1 table").css("width"));
  });
</script>
```

(the script requires jQuery but you can create a standard equivalent script if you do not want to import jQuery in your page)

Comment: This does not work, atleast not for me. [**see demo**](http://jsbin.com/AxITUxU/1/). It just places the tables on top of each other when the width reduces. Also, please in the future try just editing your existing answer if you've got changes to make to it. Unless you've got a completely unrelated other answer to add, changing your current answer is always better.

Comment: Yes it is not working in Chrome. Why is this too complex to solve?

Comment: Confirm that it does not work on all browsers.
Keep tables.
+1 for Joeytje50's answer.